# Can a batter in baseball hit a foul ball twice?

Tags: rules, baseball

Unsure if that is that most accurate way of stating my question but what happens if a batter hits a foul ball that goes near the batter and he attempts to hit it again and misses or hits the ball foul again, is he out? Does a swing and a miss again count as another strike?

Comment: I fail to see how `twice` is a useful tag...

Comment: What about the fielder that is trying to catch the foul ball?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Do you mean the batter pops up the ball and then it comes back down in a location where the same batter can take another swing at it as it comes down?

Comment: Exactly right, Tim.

Answer (score 6):

> Can a batter in baseball hit a foul ball twice?

The bat hitting the ball a second time results in a dead ball. This is covered under Rule 5.09(a)(9) in the [2016 MLB Rule Book](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf).

> After hitting or bunting a ball that continues to move over foul
>   territory, he intentionally deflects the course of the ball in any
>   manner while running to first base. The ball is dead and no runners
>   may advance;

---

> if a batter hits a foul ball that goes near the batter and he attempts to hit it again and misses or hits the ball foul again, is he out?

Yes. This is ruled interference in either case.

If the batter swings and misses on the second attempt, this will most likely be interference as the catcher will most likely have a play on fielding the ball.

This covered under Rules 6.01(a)(2) and (10).

> It is interference by a batter or a runner when:
>
> - He intentionally deflects the course of a foul ball in any manner;
> - He fails to avoid a fielder who is attempting to field a batted
>     ball.

---

> Does a swing and a miss again count as another strike?

No. The ball is dead in any scenario above.

> PENALTY FOR INTERFERENCE: The runner is out
>   and the ball is dead.